# guarantee azure worker role SLA

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have worker role on azure, but want to make sure that it can now follow microsoft SLA of 99.95% availability.
My assumption, If I go to portal and increase the instance count to 2, it would be sufficiant.

But this wording on

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/

For Cloud Services, we guarantee that when you deploy two or more role instances in different **fault and upgrade domains**, your Internet facing roles will have external connectivity at least 99.95% of the time.

What exactly does different fault and upgrade domain signify here?
and do I need to perform any additional steps to guarantee SLA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for a good explanation of [Azure Fault Domain and Upgrade Domains](http://blogs.technet.com/b/yungchou/archive/2011/05/16/window-azure-fault-domain-and-update-domain-explained-for-it-pros.aspx).  When you deploy your worker role to two instances they'll automatically be allocated to different update and fault domains so your cloud service will be supported by the SLA.  There's nothing extra you need to do.